# Select(option) element and selected attribute problems

Tags: mootools

Mootools issue (1.3.2)
Pretty strange thing happens. I am trying to set selected="yes" for option element but nothing happens. Even if i try to set attribute via $('usd').set('selected','yes') also nothing happens.

```
var select = new Element('select');
select.grab(new Element('option', {value: 'usd', selected: 'yes', text: 'usd',}));
select.grab(new Element('option', {value: 'usd',text: 'eur'}));

$('someContainer').grab(select);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select.grab(new Element('option', {value: 'usd', selected: 'yes', text: 'usd',}));
select.grab(new Element('option', {value: 'usd',text: 'eur'}));
```

You're setting selected on the first option (is selected by default), what should you expect?

P.s. - you could do set as selected also in this way:

```
new Element('option[selected]', {value: 'usd', text: 'usd',})
```

Other thing: By doing `$('usd')`, 'usd' is supposed to be an ID of an Element, so in your case you're not retrieving anything.